# Marquee tool in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, cc-2014

I am using Photoshop CC and trying to use the oval marquee tool to feather the outside edges of the photo.

But every time I make an oval selection over the subject, it blacks out the selection and feathers directly over the subject not the outside edges.

How do I make it so it feathers the border, not the selection?

Answer (score 1):

Once you've made your selection with the oval marquee tool, you can also use a layer mask to create the feather.

To do this you press on the button (below) at the bottom of the layers palette once the marquee is in place and this should mask out the oval.

[image]

If you then open the Properties palette from the menu (Window > Properties) you will see a slider that allows you to adjust the feathered edge on the mask without having a destructive impact on the image itself.

If you also click the link icon between the layer thumbnail and the layer mask icon, you can move the image independently from the mask for further refinement.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Feathering works both ways.

When you choose to feather a selection the feathering occurs at the edge of the selection and is divided - half the feathering happens outside the selection, and half the feathering occurs inside the selection.

Answer (score 0):

For Better Feather option in Adobe Photoshop CC Use **Refine Edge** command in Selection menu Here you can preview what is going on while you can increase or decrease your feather size with edges detection, Make your selection smooth and even can shift your edges. While setting all these command you also get your preview and then do <kbd>OK</kbd> to make your selection work.